# Niftynet: error: argument --axcodes: list of strings expected

Tags: python, niftynet

I have just started exploring NiftyNet, which I think will help me in my project.

I am trying to train a network for segmentation using the segmentation_application. However I built my own config.ini file and when running net_run.py I receive the error:

> "error: argument --axcodes: list of strings expected, for each list element the allowed characters: [ a-zA-Z0-9_-], but received ' ' "

I am following the configuration file requirements setting `axcodes=A,R,S`. I also tried different lists of strings ('A','R','S'; [A,R,S]; (A,R,S); ...)

My config.ini file states:

```
[T2]
csv_file = /home/jose/niftynet/data/uNet/test_data/data_file.csv
spatial_window_size = (257,257,30)
pixdim = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
axcodes= A,R,S
interp_order = 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As you've just landed at SO.. "welcome and join the club". [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) you find info how to reward a working or perhaps "the best" solution.

Answer (score 0):

Its likely you have tried `axcodes=['A', 'R', 'S']` which return only the letters 'A', 'R' and 'S' and may trigger the error because the program looks for another type of information in each string. So I think your looking for `A = str(A)` which uses the variables in the correct way, namely `'variable value A` conversion to "string A".

In case of [A, R, S] one of the variables maybe an integer. Try:

```
A = str(A)
R = str(R)
S = str(S)

axcodes = [A, R, S]
```

In case of ('A', 'R', 'S') you refer to strings in a tuple-list and not a list-list.

In case of (A,R,S) you refer to variables outside a tuple-list.

**In addition**: try to use `print "Variable "%s" is type %s" % (A, type(A))` and see what the variable "A" for type is.

**Edit 1**:

Try the following (file: rootfolder "." included; brackets placed and `interp_order` increased to default value)

```
csv_file = ./home/jose/niftynet/data/uNet/test_data/data_file.csv
spatial_window_size = (257,257,30)
pixdim = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
axcodes= (A,R,S)
interp_order = 3
```

**Edit 2**:

Based on the documentation [here](http://nipy.org/nibabel/reference/nibabel.orientations.html#nibabel.orientations.axcodes2ornt) it should be `axcodes=('A', 'R', 'S')` but you said that you tried that. Perhaps the order of letter is key.

Comment: I am using the command line to start the application and using a config file to set the parameters. Therefore debugging as you suggested is not straight forward. Also, str() command doesn't work. It seems like a problem of how to read the config.ini file which I still haven't found.

Comment: Then I recommend to post more info about how you start application and the application code (essentials) itself so people can check what's going on. Perhaps posting example part of `config.ini` possible?

Comment: In this page you may find the documentation for the configuration file: https://cmiclab.cs.ucl.ac.uk/CMIC/NiftyNet/blob/dev/config/README.md#global-niftynet-settings

An example part of my config.ini:
"...
pixdim = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
axcodes= A,R,S
interp_order = 1
"

Comment: Please post the config file at the end of your question.

Comment: The config file is python style ran and as far as I can see the array-style is tuple-bracketed at all times (numpy accepts only `[]` so `NiBabel` converts them internally). You may have to add tuple-brackets elsewhere in your config as well. See proomise12 example [here](https://github.com/NifTK/NiftyNet/blob/dev/demos/PROMISE12/promise12_demo_train_config.ini).

Comment: After following Edit1 and Edit2 from your comment, problem still persists.  (`...but received ' '` for `axcodes=(A,R,S)` and `...but received ('A', 'R', 'S')` for `axcodes=('A', 'R', 'S')`)

Comment: I hope that works for you......  otherwise there is always the Osiris option [here](http://www.osirix-viewer.com/osirix/osirix-md/) but cost coins and can't be modified codingwise by you ;-p

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the rest of the config.ini file.

On `[parcellation]` section I had one other `axcodes=''` which was giving the error.